# CSS no funciona cuando trabajo en localhost:8080

Tags: html, css

Estoy creando un sitio web y tengo problemas en cargar la hoja de estilos CSS en mi documento HTML cuando estoy trabajando en `localhost:8080` y no entiendo por qué.

La estructura de mi repertorio es la siguiente:

```
.
|-- node_modules
|-- ressources
|   |-- css
|   |   `-- oanstyle.css
|   `-- images
|       |-- img1.jpg
|       |-- img2.jpg
|       `-- etc
|-- app.js
|-- index.html
|-- package-lock.json
`-- package.json
```

Utilizo `app.listen(8080)` y no me carga ni la hoja de estilos ni las imágenes que tengo en la carpeta. He probado:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./ressources/css/oanstyle.css">
```

También he probado:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ressources/css/oanstyle.css">
```

Y:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080//ressources/css/oanstyle.css">
```

Para las imágenes he probado lo mismo.  ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76198/discussion-on-question-by-guillem-puig-comerma-css-no-funciona-cuando-trabajo-en).

Comment: ¿Qué servidor web estas usando?, ¿es node.js?, sería bueno que indicaras el código que tienes en el app.js y el index.html y capturas de pantalla de la terminal cuando levantas el servidor y haces una petición. Trata de especificar este tipo de información al hacer este tipo de preguntas, por tu árbol de archivos medio se puede inferir el servidor node.js pero la mayoría de la gente pensaría por default en un servidor Apache, o nada más no encuentro donde lo especificas, también ¿estas usando ningún tipo de framework para node.js?

Comment: Puedes comprobar en el navegador si te carga la hoja de estilos o no y por qué ocurre. Puedes ir a Inspeccionar elemento > Red, recarga la página. ¿Qué te aparece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con el fin de dar respuesta a la inquietud es necesario revisar con la siguiente URL:

```
http://localhost:8080//ressources/css/oanstyle.css
```

En tu navegador para saber si existe el archivo de estilos... dependiendo de si no existe (err 404 no found) o tiene problemas de acceso (err 500 internal server error), tendrás que validar el estado del archivo y las rutas relativas que te informo en tu código html, cambiando en tus links de css lo siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ressources/css/oanstyle.css">
```

La jerarquía de directorios en un server se desplaza con `(../../)` si quieres subir dos niveles de tu jerarquía por ejemplo y así vas colocando en lugar de tus rutas absolutas para volverlas relativas, al realizar este proceso debería funcionarte con normalidad tu llamado css en html.

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: José primero muchas gracias. Segundo, no mu funciona. Llevo mucho rato y no encuentro solución, ya no se que hacer.

Comment: Guillem porfa ingresa al chat que Sebastian a abierto para tener respuesta a tu inquietud. Saludos: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76002/javascript-server

Comment: @GuillemPuigcomerma ya tienes rep suficiente  para el chat. Un saludo